# Can c++ code read java .class files?

Tags: java, c++, compilation, .class-file

I have been working in java for a while now, and want to learn how c++ works when it comes to compilation and executed.

I was wondering if there is a way to convert compiled c++ class into .class files in java and vice versa. I am interested in a single format that can be used both by java code as well as c++ code that can be directly executed to see the results.

Comment: have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ and jvm is writen with c/c++

Comment: ¬_¬ you want to take compiled C++ code that would be specific to certain platforms... and convert it to java byte code... to what end? to compare the 'performance' (which will surely be shattered by this meddling). Do you even understand what you are asking for?

Answer (score 5):

Almost everything *can be done* if you are ambitious and stubborn enough, however, the question lies usually in time and cost and features..

In its core, Java *language* is a subset of C++. There are some syntactic sugars added that may make you feel that there is "something more", like anonymous class implementation or hidden pointers to outer classes, but it is just a thin layer of syntax, which is irrelevant once the code gets compiled.

After compilation, C++ code is represented by machine code. Java's bytecode of course is translatable to machine code - simply by the fact that JVM executes it and that the jitter can  recompile it on the fly into machine code..

So, roughly speaking, every Java code, compiled or not, is translatable to C++.

However, there are some code constructs in C++ that can be compiled into machine code, but that *maybe* are representable in Java's bytecode, but that *cannot* be represented back in the Java language. There are lots of it: from some easy to go around like passing parameters as references, to more complex ones like pointer (TheList->) arithmetics, to some really painful to translate like multiple inheritance, custom memory management (that is, overloaded operators new and delete), or some wicked types like unions.

So, clearly, C++ code is not translatable to Java. Clearly, C++ compiled code is even more not translatable, as C++ compilers often optimize the products thorougly, so that it is very hard to guess what was the 'classes' or 'functions' like..

However, if you limit the C++ language, and restrict yourself to not use any of those hard-to-translate constructs (see 'TheList'), then you can make the C++ code translatable. Again, code, but not binaries.

This is not all though. The 'translatability' is one thing, but the other is: will it run? The most distinctive runtime difference is the GarbageCollector. Let's say you actually managed to translate some Java code into C++, and you lined it up with C++ application. Your Java/C++ code executes and creates some objects. Who will clean them up? Typically, there's no GC in C++. Your Java code will therefore leak -- or you will have to provide/implement some kind of GC for the Java/C++ code.. Not pretty. Of course you can limit Java code to not create any objects, d'oh.

Do not get me wrong: even those hard-to-translate things like pointer arithmetics etc are translatable: you can *generate* tons of helper/wireup code that will replace them with 'proper things of the second platform'. It will, however, be ridiculously complex and slow. I don't think anyone sane will ever try.

So, the only thing that would seem to be left available is very-limited-C++-code <-> somewhat-limited-Java-code. If we cut down the question to this, then yes, that should be translatable. *But*..

What does it mean to *translate* code? How'd you do it? You have to read, process, *analyze* the source code, and then *somehow* produce the other code in the other language. Well, ok. Producing code is simple, it's just text. But, have you ever tried to *analyze* code? Long story short, let me just tell you that reading/parsing Java code is at least an **order of magnitude easier** that reading/parsing C++ code. Java was partly desined to be easily parsable by relatively simple algorithms. If you drop any attempts to optimize, writing a Java parser/compiler is relatively simple thing. On the other hand, C++ was not. Like Java, to parse C++ properly you'd have to effectively create a custom C++ compiler, but also a preprocessor. To some extent, you might also need to implement some parts of the linker. To make thins a little worse, C++ evolved from older languages and is literally packed with some once-in-your-lifetime-used features that make the syntax *really* difficult to *accurately* process (ie. have you ever used **[alternate token set](http://cpprocks.com/if-arr-not_eq-0-and-not-false-alternative-tokens-in-c/)**? ..and this is only beginning:)). Do not get scared too much, though! I just want to give you a feeling what you try to touch. You probably would'nt need to write it. Such already tools exists, both for Java (really many, actually) and for C++ (few, and I bet the reasonable ones are not-fully-for-free.. or maybe you could use the GCC toolset probably..). They produce machine-processable representations of the sourcecode, and if you really want to do some translating job, I'd suggest you start there.

Of course my knowledge can be off by a few years, and maybe someone already has written some moreorless working translator - I'd love to see it!

If not, I think it is not worth it. Try embedding Java's runtime in your C++ app, or talk from Java to C++ DLLs via JNI. It is *much* simplier!

Comment: A bit late, but java is definitely *not* a subset of c++. Not every c++ program is a valid java program, and not every java program is a valid c++ program.

Comment: @0x150 I suggest rereading my answer. You've clearly referring to the meaning of 'subset' as in word-for-word or even character-for-character reuse of the same source code under different environment, result of which is pretty obvious and can't be really argued about. But in doing so you seem to have disregarded sth like 90-95% of the text I wrote those 10yrs ago :) I wrote the same thing you said, between the lines. Then tried to make it clear I dont mean "literal direct reuse" but "translation" into acceptable forms that have the same/similar use/outcome. Cheers and have a great new year!

Answer (score 3):

Compiled C++ code is loaded by the OS. That is, the C++ linker generate OS dependent executable modules. Whereas Java .class is loaded by the JVM. JVM executes Java byte code.

If you want to make a Java byte code loader/runner, you could start from JVM source code.
=> [link](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/)

If you are aimed to load/execute compiled C++ code in Java envirionment, following are required.
(Assuming 32bit Windows platform)

. PE parser/loader => [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)
. X86 CPU instruction parser(?) => [link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)
. X86 instruction to Java byte code translator

In short, its almost impossible.

For simple C/C++ vs. Java interoperations, JNI will do. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think, [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) will be useful:

"The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call, and to be called by, native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly."

[Here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jni/simple-example-of-using-the-java-native-interface.html)  are good tips how to program a simple example of using the Java Native Interfac (write a Java application that calls a C function).

Comment: JNI let's Java interface with native code... clue is in the name. It does not provide a way to convert compiled C++ code into java byte code.

Answer (score 0):

Converting already compiled C++ code to JVM bytecode is not an easy task, especially if you want to be able to use compiled C++ code from multiple platforms.

It will probably be easier to make a JVM-backend for [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) instead. The drawback here is that people who wants this functionality must use your compiler.

In short, if you want to write code targeting the Java virtual machine, then use a language and compiler already made to do it. Like Java...